# How to compile cli-clock on cygwin using Makefile?

Tags: c, cygwin

I wrote `ggc clock.c -o clock` assuming that it would compile to the file "clock" but apparently not. I do see it comes with a Makefile except I'm not quite sure on how you use that.

Here's the link to what i'm using. 
https://github.com/Unixhub/cli-clock

```
clock.c:6:21: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
clock.c:54: error: parse error before "WINDOW"
clock.c:54: warning: no semicolon at end of struct or union
clock.c:56: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
clock.c:68: error: parse error before '*' token
clock.c:68: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
clock.c: In function `init':
clock.c:89: error: request for member `bg' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:95: error: `stdscr' undeclared (first use in this function)
clock.c:95: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
clock.c:95: error: for each function it appears in.)
clock.c:99: error: `OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
clock.c:100: error: request for member `bg' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:102: error: request for member `bg' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:102: error: request for member `bg' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:103: error: request for member `bg' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:103: error: request for member `option' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:104: error: request for member `option' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:104: error: request for member `bg' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:115: error: request for member `running' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:116: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:117: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:118: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:119: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:120: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:121: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:122: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:122: error: request for member `lt' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:123: error: request for member `lt' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:127: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:127: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:128: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:129: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:130: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:131: error: `LINES' undeclared (first use in this function)
clock.c:131: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:132: error: `COLS' undeclared (first use in this function)
clock.c:132: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:133: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:135: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `signal_handler':
clock.c:149: error: request for member `running' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `update_hour':
clock.c:158: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:158: error: request for member `lt' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:159: error: request for member `lt' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:161: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:164: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:165: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:168: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:168: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:169: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:169: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:172: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:172: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:173: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:173: error: request for member `tm' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `draw_number':
clock.c:189: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:190: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:192: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `draw_clock':
clock.c:200: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:201: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:204: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:205: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:206: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:209: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:210: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:213: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:214: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:215: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:218: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:219: error: request for member `date' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `clock_move':
clock.c:224: error: request for member `framewin' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:224: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:224: error: request for member `geo' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `key_event':
clock.c:231: error: request for member `option' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:232: error: `stdscr' undeclared (first use in this function)
clock.c:235: error: request for member `running' in something not a structure or union
clock.c: In function `main':
clock.c:247: error: request for member `option' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:247: error: `COLOR_BLUE' undeclared (first use in this function)
clock.c:248: error: request for member `option' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:250: error: request for member `running' in something not a structure or union
clock.c:259:2: warning: no newline at end of file
```

Comment: If there is a Makefile, it is meant as input to the `make` utility. Try `make`. You might need to install other packages, at least `ncurses` and/or something called `ncurses-devel` or similar. Check the requisites (probably a file called INSTALL or README in the sources).

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin is large and only a small part of it is usually installed by default. The rest is divided into separately installed packages.

You need to add at least the `libncurses-devel` package, and possibly others. Run `setup.exe`, answer the usual questions, type `ncurses` in the search line, select the last version of `libncurses-devel`, continue with the installation.

If there's a Makefile, type `make` in the directory where it resides. This will run the build process.

Note that nothing whatsoever is guaranteed unless the program was tested in Cygwin.